# Performance Profiling Service Fabric dependent application

Tags: performance, azure-service-fabric

We are facing a challenging situation, we have one ASP.NET Core 2.2 service  that is completely dependent on service fabric and we cannot run it outside the cluster (due to wrong intermingled design that made the application totally dependent on underlying service fabric features).

Now, we are facing performance issues in the application we are trying to troubleshoot, but unfortunately, neither Visual Studio Profiler nor Reshaper can attach to service fabric services. Is there any way I can performance profile the service?

Comment: Is this in a production cluster that you want to remotely debug?  When you say intermingled design, does that mean the performance issue might be related to another service running on the cluster?  If so, there may be multiple instances of the service you're trying to debug.

I'd suggest putting some metrics into the application using application insights, then when you have an idea of where the issue is, re-create it locally and use profiling to determine the cause.

Comment: The issue occurs both in local and production clusters. By intermingled design I meant that the services cannot run outside Service Fabric (e.g. IIS Express) because they rely on some service fabric features such as reliable dictionaries and naming services on their very first phases (startup.cs).
I tried checking app insights metrics but could not locate something useful, it is most likely because there are too chatty requests causing the service slowness and not one long running request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to measure performance using .NET

> StopWatch ()

not the best solution but helped to fix the issue.